# Bulk download of arXiv (or other publication data set) with metadata AND citations

Tags: citations, arxiv, data, pubmed

This is to extend the question:
[Getting a dump of arXiv metadata](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38969/getting-a-dump-of-arxiv-metadata)

I would like to download arXiv in bulk, and found a useful answer above for using this syntax:

```
http://export.arxiv.org/oai2?verb=ListRecords&set=math&from=2015-01-01&until=2015-01-31&metadataPrefix=arXiv
```

However, in data there is not a field for citations.
I wonder if there is another dataset.

In
https://arxiv.org/help/bulk_data
there is no description about citations, apart of an old dataset (KDD) of 2003.

Is there any parameter to extend the above query and also fetch citations?
Is there any reference to see how arXiv metadata are classified?

Any other dataset of articles possible to freely download?
I would like to use a dump for testing visualizations for knowledge discovery. If there is already a sample DB standardized / polished, it will be really helpful not to have to polish / curate data.

Comment: [This](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/58407/7223) answer might be related to the second part of your question (getting citation counts to articles), but it does not allow for bulk downloads of citations.

Comment: What do you mean by "see how arxiv metadata are classified"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

arXiv's metadata does not include any citation information.

If you are interested in citations in arXiv documents, your best bet is probably to extract them from the PDF files using a dedicated tool ([Cermine](http://cermine.ceon.pl/index.html), [pdfx](http://pdfx.cs.man.ac.uk/usage) or [pdfextract](http://labs.crossref.org/pdfextract/) for instance), or from the LaTeX sources, by inspecting the `.aux` files.

You can download PDF or source files using the [dedicated bulk data interface](https://arxiv.org/help/bulk_data_s3). Using the OAI interface for this purpose is not recommended as it generates a lot of traffic on the main arXiv site.

You could extract a similar dataset from PubMed Central using [their API](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/tools/openftlist/). If you are looking for something broader (not restricted to a particular topic), you could use [COnnecting REpositories](http://core.ac.uk) (they have full texts from a variety of sources, with an API).

You can also use a pre-curated dataset such as the [Microsoft Academic Graph](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/mag/).

Comment: Thank you for CORE - did not know that. Are you saying that to extract metadata of citations one need to parse pdf by pdf ? It would be quite of a work for standardizing all the elements and typos and such. I thought citations may have been already cleaned by publishers. Is it not available publicly in bulk (e.g. at least, one can download patents corpus from google in xML, but at least XML not pdf!)

Comment: If you are looking for a clean dataset of citations, have a look at the last sentence of my answer :-)

Answer (score 5):

Since recently, arXiv citation information is available from [Semantic Scholar](https://www.semanticscholar.org/) -- it is the one that is displayed on the arXiv website.

Semantic Scholar apparently provides a [dump](https://api.semanticscholar.org/corpus/) of their data.