# How to retrieve number of citations for a list of papers?

Tags: citations, google-scholar

I have a long list of papers in a word file and I want to quickly retrieve how often each of them has been cited to get a quick (although of course somewhat rough) idea of which ones are the most influential. Is there a tool that allows to retrieve for a list of papers from e.g. Google Scholar the number of times each of them has been cited? I would prefer not to have to check manually for each paper on Google Scholar.

Comment: I doubt any tools that such a functionality given just a list of paper names. You could write a simple script to do this for you though.

Comment: @AustinHenley Hmmh, I had hoped that some site like http://www.scopus.com/ would be able to do this. How would you write such a script in that case, because I know for instance that Scholar does not have an official API. I might ask on stackoverflow otherwise.

Comment: Does your list include DOIs? If so, and you can parse these out, you can drop those into Scopus/WoS a hundred or so at a time.

Comment: @Andrew It doesn't unfortunately.

Comment: You can also use `R` and [scholar](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/132191/45105) package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution to [programmatically retrieve Google Scholar results](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10188/903) is [scholar.py](https://github.com/ckreibich/scholar.py) (open source,  BSD license), which is

> a Python module that implements a querier and parser for Google Scholar's output. Its classes can be used independently, but it can also be invoked as a command-line tool.

Amongst other things, it can fetch the number of citations of an article.