# How to retrieve the total number of unique citations of a group of authors

Tags: citations, google-scholar, research-group, scopus, web-of-science

I'm writing a joint research proposal for a finance institution. One of the ways to justify working with another group is showing metrics of how many papers they have published and how many citations they have.

If you want these data for one person, this can be easily found (Google scholar, Web of Science, Scopus...). But what about a group of researchers, considering that many of them are co-authors of the same articles?

E.g. Researcher A has 2400 total citations, Researcher B has 1500 and Researcher C has 400, but, since they are all from the same group and are co-authors of many articles, the total unique citations of the three researchers is only 2600, not the sum.

I have only found [this Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/65119) question regarding the number of citations for a list of papers, which isn't exactly what I'm looking for, since the *unique* citations for the authors aren't taken into account.

Comment: I don't think there is a tool for this. You'd probably have to do the work yourself.

Comment: Maybe try this Python package? https://pypi.org/project/scholarly/

Comment: I was getting some info from `scholarly` trying to implement anpami's idea. But I think Google Scholar blocked my IP... I'll try again on another computer or after a couple of days

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to code, this would be the approach:

First, get the DOIs for each of the authors' publications.

Second (option 1), loop the DOIs through the [*CrossRef* API](https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc) in the form of `https://api.crossref.org/works/[DOI]` ([example](https://api.crossref.org/works/10.1002/adfm.201505328)).

Second (option 2), loop the DOIs through the [*OpenCitations* API](https://opencitations.net/index/coci/api/v1#/citations/%7Bdoi%7D) in the form of `https://opencitations.net/index/coci/api/v1/citations/[DOI]` and fetch the field `is-referenced-by-count` ([example](https://opencitations.net/index/coci/api/v1/citation-count/10.1002/adfm.201505328)).

Third, sum up the citation counts such that every distinct (cited) DOI appears only once.